# Get number of available instances in ec2 using java api

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using `com.amazonaws.services.ec2` for creating instances in ec2.

But ec2 have VM limit.

Is there any method to get the avilable instance count using this java api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can call trust advisor api to check that - https://console.aws.amazon.com/trustedadvisor/home?#/category/service-limits

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you please quote the method name ?

Comment: I have done same using python SDK. I think this is for Java - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/support/AWSSupportClient.html.

Comment: Use this method - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/support/model/DescribeTrustedAdvisorCheckResultResult.html and you need to give id for check as well. In your case it will be checkId='eW7HH0l7J9'

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using support api for trust advisor. you need to make API call to service limits and need to process the results to get a specific number of units available in EC2 limit.

Service limit aws - https://console.aws.amazon.com/trustedadvisor/home?#/category/service-limits

Java API -
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/support/AWSSupportClient.html

Method - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/support/model/DescribeTrustedAdvisorCheckResultResult.html

Service limit check id  - eW7HH0l7J9

Comment: Thanks for your timely help.